# How to run cassandra erlang client through command line?

Tags: erlang, cassandra, erlang-driver

I could not build and test following cassandra erlang client in ubuntu. https://github.com/matehat/cqerl#connecting.How to do it?

Comment: So what happens when you attempt to build it? Error message?

Comment: I am getting {badmatch,error} while executing above project by issuing make test command.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/dieswaytoofast/erlang_cassandra.git
cd erlang_cassandra
rebar get-deps    
rebar compile
```

Note: I am new to Erlang and Cassandra